# Casted a delete vote, says 27 votes remaining

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, vote-to-delete

Two users cast a delete vote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21282141/1542290), one was me, but when I went back to the question it revoked the delete votes and this is what am seeing

[image]

So where are the votes which were cast just few minutes back?

> Note: I again cast a delete vote, and now I am seeing the count 1

---

This is what my profile shows after casting another delete vote

> [image]

Comment: You sure it isn't a simple browser caching issue?

Comment: @PeeHaa Running always on Icognito, also the votes are revoked, and so I was able to cast twice, I have shared the screen as well

Comment: Could it have something to do with the OP himself having deleted his question?

Comment: @Stijn Now that reminds me ... that when I was refreshing the page, something like *deleted* with a red highlight was appeared, but it refreshed back, that may be the case, but the delete votes shouldn't be revoked

Comment: By design. Undelete reset any past delete votes, if two 10K+ users will cast delete votes OP can "clear" them by deleting and undeleting. Looking for existing report on Meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Should be changed, I guess OP knew that and he did that on purpose

Comment: Couldn't find it, feel free to start bug/feature request about it (e.g. "Preserve past delete votes when post is deleted by OP")

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure will do that

Comment: There, now he can't keep undeleting/deleting his question. ;P

Comment: Marked it as bydesign. The user was definitely abusing it, I'll try to get some attention to this. A [meta-tag:feature-request] would be helpful

Comment: @m0sa http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217216/205030