# Delete votes shouldn't reset if OP deletes question himself

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

Yesterday I asked [a question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217080/casted-a-delete-vote-says-27-votes-remaining), where the issue I complained about delete votes which disappeared. It turns out that the system resets the votes if the Asker deletes and undeletes his question, which was "status by design" as [commented by @m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217080/casted-a-delete-vote-says-27-votes-remaining#comment703842_217080) .

So I would like to request a feature where the deleted votes by others shouldn't be revoked if a user deletes and undeletes his own question; the delete votes of the users who cast before should be retained.

Comment: 4 votes in 40 seconds, seems popular

Comment: Holy unicorns... 4 upvotes in less than a minute!!

Comment: Guess would be more if everyone who ever seen it abused would vote ;)

Comment: Great! Now I know the way to abuse deletion votes :p

Comment: @AlmaDo enjoy it while you still can

Comment: I don't know who voted to reopen this, but if it isn't a duplicate this particular request might need some revision to clearly state how it's different.

Comment: @Bart I casted that, cuz you deleted the possible duplicate comment.. which you shouldn't delete... so it clearly states that you wanted to divert the traffic to your question.. As a reputed user, you shouldn't delete those comments..

Comment: @Mr.Alien those comments are automatically included on first vote, and removed by the system once duplicate closure is a fact. This is not a manual action I've taken. I have no real interest in diverting attention from your request to mine, other than for the fact that's it's a exact duplicate. Something I realized because, well, I asked the same thing. Can happen, no harm done.

Comment: @Bart It's fine, anyways it's a valid close vote :) but I found that deleting the comment wasn't necessary, and yes I know the system auto comments, I close hell lot of questions, so anyways, you got a point

Comment: Once again, just to clarify, I didn't delete it. It's the system that does that automatically.

Comment: Agreed it's a dupe, no idea how I didn't find it... I searched a lot before [suggesting the OP here to start a new request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217080/casted-a-delete-vote-says-27-votes-remaining#comment703345_217080). /cc @Bart

Comment: Anyway @Mr.Alien you got a fair amount of points, win-win situation :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess bart didn't used the right keywords... may be thats why you didn't find it, but whoever questions this, the point is that the design for this should be changed

Comment: Agreed, and it's good to have your post as well. More key words now!

Comment: I'll also point out this side-effect of self-deletions: [Don't automatically dismiss spam / offensive flags when a post is deleted by the owner](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175420/dont-automatically-dismiss-spam-offensive-flags-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-the)

Comment: @BradLarson I didn't knew that it dismisses them too..